# getsupportactionbar() returning null/crashing on Gingerbread

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

After trying to add Gingerbread support to my app and failing (crashes on all Activities) I wrote some test code to work out the problem.

I'm extending SherlockFragment Activity.

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    ActionBar ab;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        String themestring = prefs.getString("theme","holo_colour");


        if (themestring.equals("holo_dark_colour")){
            setTheme(R.style.DarkBlueTheme);
        }
        if (themestring.equals("holo_colour")){
            setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.gtest);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ab = getSupportActionBar(); //crash!

    }
```

But i cannot for the life of me get it to stop crashing on Gingerbread, its working fine on 4.0 +.

The theme set dynamically:

```
<style name="BlueTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/BlueActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/BlueActionBar</item>

</style>


<style name="BlueActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#33b5e5</item>
    <item name="background">#33b5e5</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>

</style>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried looking at your logs to see exactly what the problem is?

Comment: Where is your logcat crash ? Post it fast.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Sherlock Library for `ActionBar` in lower versions
But Android it self have a library to use `ActionBar` in lower versions
Follow this tutorial [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) to do that.